# ElasticSearch - invalid date-time format in mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following dynamic template in my mapping.

```
 "dt": {
    "match": "*Time",
    "mapping": {
       "type": "date",
       "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS||yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
    }
 }
```

Yet when I insert a doc with "BirthTime" : "1992-05-06T00:00:00Z" I receive the following error:

```
"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Invalid format: [yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ]: Illegal pattern component: T"
```

I thought my datetime format is an ISO standard that ES should understand out of the box. What should my mapping format be to support BirthTime?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

`"format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"`

instead of

`"format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS||yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"`

Comment: Worked! Any pointers to why this works or where in the docs? Thanks again!

Comment: Elasticsearch uses Joda for date time operations. Refer: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html